# Why is this creating two inputs instead of one

Tags: c

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXRxv.png

As shown in the link above I have to input '<' twice instead of once, why is that? Also it seems that the first input is ignored but the second '<' is the one the program recognizes.

The same thing occurs even without a loop too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){

  int randomGen, upper, lower, end, newRandomGen;
  char answer;

  upper = 100;
  lower = 1;
  end = 1;

  do {

   srand(time(0));
   randomGen = rand()%(upper + lower);
   printf("%d\n", randomGen);
   scanf("%s\n", &answer);

  }while(answer != '=');





}
```

Comment: `%s` into one char is risky (i.e. wrong). It'll try to write a terminator out of bounds.

Comment: ... which is quite possibly why it's broken. Please use the answer section for answers, @Ry-, not the comments section.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I didn't think that was why it was broken, so, comment.

Comment: @Ry- That's exactly why we have a peer review system on answers. As a mod you should know how Q&A works please! Use the comments section for requesting clarification.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Post advice I think doesn't answer the question in the answer section in the hopes that peer review will delete it? Questionable.

Comment: Sad to see a mod not comprehending the basic principles of the Q&A site. Obviously this won't go anywhere useful, so let's move on.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "use comments to request clarification **or suggest improvements**" (e.g. pointing out UB so it can be removed to make the question more focused). I think that fits?

Comment: I changed it to %c still doesn't fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

Whitespace in `scanf` format strings, like the `\n` in `"%c\n"`, tries to match any amount of whitespace, and `scanf` doesn’t know that there’s no whitespace left to skip until it encounters something that isn’t whitespace (like the second character you type) or the end of input. You provide it with `=\n`, which fills in the `%c` and waits until the whitespace is over. Then you provide it with another `=` and `scanf` returns. The second time around, the character could be anything and it’d still work.

Skip *leading* whitespace instead (and use the correct specifier for one character, `%c`, as has been mentioned):

```
scanf(" %c", &answer);
```

Also, it’s good practice to make sure you actually succeeded in reading something, especially when failing to read something means leaving it uninitialized and trying to read it later (another example of undefined behaviour). So check `scanf`’s return value, which should match the number of conversion specifiers you provided:

```
if (scanf(" %c", &answer) != 1) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been commented, you should not use the scanf format `%s` if you want to read a single character. Indeed, you should never use the scanf format `%s` for any purpose, because it will read an arbitrary number of characters into the buffer you supply, so you have no way to ensure that your buffer is large enough. So you should *always* supply a maximum character count. For example, `%1s` will read only one character. But note: that will still not work with a `char` variable, since it reads a *string* and in C, strings are arrays of `char` *terminated with a `NUL`*. (`NUL` is the character whose value is 0, also sometimes spelled `\0`. You could just write it as 0, but don't confuse that with the character `'0'` (whose value is 48, in most modern systems).

So a string containing a single character actually occupies two bytes: the character itself, and a `NUL`.

If you just want to read a single character, you could use the format `%c`. `%c` has a few differences from `%s`, and you need to be aware of all of them:

1. The default maximum length read by `%s` is "unlimited". The default for `%c` is 1, so `%c` is identical to `%1c`.
2. `%s` will put a `NUL` at the end of the characters read (which you need to leave space for), so the result is a C string. `%c` does not add the `NUL`, so you only need to leave enough space for the characters themselves.
3. `%s` skips whitespace before storing any characters. `%c` does not ignore whitespace. Note: a newline character (at the end of each line) is considered whitespace.

So, based on the first two rules, you could use either of the following:

```
char theShortString[2];
scanf("%1s", theShortString);
char theChar = theShortString[0];
```

or

```
char theChar;
scanf("%c", &theChar);
```

Now, when you used

```
scanf("%s", &theChar);
```

you will cause `scanf` to write a `NUL` (that is, a zero) in the byte *following `theChar`*, which quite possibly is part of a different variable. That's really bad. Don't do that. Ever. Even if you get away with it today, it will get you into serious trouble some time soon.

But that's not the problem here. The problem here is with what comes after the `%s` format code.

Let's take a minute (ok, maybe half an hour) to read the documentation of `scanf`, by typing `man scanf`. What we'll see, quite near the beginning, is: (emphasis added)

> A directive is one of the following:
>
> - A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.; see `isspace(3)`). This directive matches **any amount of white space**, including none, in the input.

So when you use `"%s\n"`, `scanf` will do the following:

1. skip over any white-space characters in the input buffer.
2. read the following word up to but not including the next white-space character, and store it in the corresponding argument, followed by a `NUL`.
3. skip over any white-space following the word which it just read.

It does the last step because `\n` — a newline — is itself white-space, as noted in the quote from the manpage.

Now, what you actually typed was `<` followed by a newline, so the word read at step 2 will be just he character `<`. The newline you typed afterwards is white-space, so it will be ignored by step 3. But that doesn't satisfy step 3, because `scanf` (as documented) will ignore "any amount of white space". It doesn't know that there isn't more white space coming. You might, for example, be intending to type a blank line (that is, just a newline), in which case `scanf` must skip over that newline as well. So `scanf` keeps on reading.

Since the input buffer is now empty, the I/O library must now read the next line, which it does. And now you type another `<` followed by a newline. Clearly, the `<` is not white-space, so `scanf` leaves it in the input buffer and returns, knowing that it has done its duty.

Your program then checks the word read by `scanf` and realises that it is not an `=`. So it loops again, and the `scanf` executes again. Now there is already data in the input buffer (the second `<` which you typed), so `scanf` can immediately store that word. But it will again try to skip "any amount of white space" afterwards, which by the same logic as above will cause it to read a third line of input, which it leaves in the input buffer.

The end result is that you always need to type the next line before the previous line is passed back to your program. Obviously that's not what you want.

So what's the solution? Simple. **Don't put a `\n` at the end of your format string.**

Of course, you do want to skip that newline character. But you don't need to skip it until the next call to `scanf`. If you used a `%1s` format code, `scanf` would automatically skip white-space before returning input, but as we've seen above, `%c` is far simpler if you only want to read a single character. Since `%c` does not skip white-space before returning input, you need to insert an explicit directive to do so:  a white-space character. It's usual to use an actual space rather than a newline for this purpose, so we would normally write this loop as:

```
char answer;
srand(time(0)); /* Only call srand once, at the beginning of the program */
do {
   randomGen = rand()%(upper + lower);  /* This is not right */
   printf("%d\n", randomGen);
   scanf(" %c", &answer);
} while (answer != '=');
```

Comment: Than you so much for the response, can you further clarify why the randomGen is not right?

Comment: @anubhav: Suppose upper is 2 and lower is 4, so you want a random number between 2 and 4. But you get a random number between 0 and 5, because that's what `rand()%6` gives you. What you want is `lower + rand()%(upper + 1 - lower)` assuming that `lower` and `upper` defines an *inclusive* range. (If you meant from `lower` to `upper` not including `upper`, then ditch the `+ 1`.)

Answer (score -1):

```
 scanf("%s\n", &answer);
```

Here you used the `%s` flag in the format string, which tells `scanf` to read as many characters as possible into a pre-allocated array of `char`s, then a null terminator to make it a C-string.

However, `answer` is a single `char`. Just writing the terminator is enough to go out of bounds, causing *undefined behaviour* and strange mishaps.

Instead, you should have used `%c`. This reads a single character into a `char`.